# Can I return to Brazil with a recently expired passport?

Tags: visas, passports, international-travel, brazilian-citizens

I am studying in the USA right now, and I have a student visa. I am a Brazilian citizen. My problem is that my passport expires (not my visa) 4 days before I go back to Brazil for the summer. Can I would be able to go back to my country even if my passport is expired?

Comment: I can't see it being a problem, especially if your flight doesn't stop in any third countries. You'll need to renew it while home though.

Comment: Well it could be a problem if he is denied boarding due to not presenting valid ID to verify his/her identity. The TSA probably accept a valid US driver's license as alternative document, though.

Comment: @DCTLib Oops, misread the question as "4 days **after** I go back". Yes, that definitley could be an issue.

Comment: Not sure I understand why a person would be refused boarding to his own country of citizenship.

Comment: @CGCampbell I've read on this site that India refuses entry to its citizens who have expired passports. Brazil obviously doesn't, but without asking the question one wouldn't know.

Comment: Picturing stateless Indians flitting about the Earth....

Answer (score 2):

According to TIMATIC:

> Passport required.
>   - Nationals of Brazil are allowed to enter with an expired passport.

So you should be okay as long as you have a direct flight.

If you're nonetheless worried about potential problems, though, you can renew your passport now.  There's no requirement to wait until it has expired.

EDIT: DCTLib pointed out that you might have trouble getting past the TSA security checkpoint.  They require "valid" ID, though there are provisions for letting people fly when they've forgotten or lost their identification. You may be able to benefit from these provisions when you have a recently expired ID, but it might be more difficult for you if you don't live in the US.  To be perfectly safe on this point, renew your passport now.