# Can I travel to Brazil and back from the US with an expired Brazilian passport?

Tags: passports

I am a dual citizen (American/Brazilian) living in the US and have booked a round-trip to Brazil in July for 2 weeks. I found out my Brazilian passport expired in May. The American passport is fine.

1. I found out I can enter Brazil, but will I be stopped in the US? (Because I assume they see where you are going)
2. Can I leave Brazil to go back?
3. I'm passing through Panama on my way to Brazil and on my way back. Does that affect anything?

Comment: (1) The US has no government-operated passport control on exit. They do occasionally screen departing passengers directly, but even if they do this, they don't pay attention to your admissibility at your destination. Your valid US passport satisfies US immigration law with respect to your departure from the US. The airline *will* stop you by refusing to let you on the plane if they don't think you will be admitted at your destination; you should therefore be certain that TIMATIC notes that expired Brazilian passports are valid for entry into Brazil. (2) I don't know. (3) It shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

The question of whether you can enter Brazil with your expired passport has already been answered here on Travel.SE - [Can I return to Brazil with a recently expired passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65369/can-i-return-to-brazil-with-a-recently-expired-passport)

However returning to the US will be a different matter. According to the [Brazilian Consulate in Houston](http://houston.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/faq_-_frequently_asked_questions.xml#25) website :

> Brazilian citizens, even those with dual citizenship, must enter and
>   leave Brazil with a Brazilian passport.

So you're fine to enter Brazil, but not to leave.

Your options are either to obtain a new Brazilian passport (either in the US or Brazil), or to renounce your Brazilian citizenship, at which point you will be able to travel with your US passport.

Comment: In light of the consulate's statement and the fact that an expired passport satisfies it for entry, how do you conclude that the expired passport does not satisfy it for exit?

Comment: Because that's not how passports work.

Comment: "how passports work" varies from country to country based on each country's laws.  Some countries allow citizens to return with expired passports, others nominally don't.  The same could be true for departure, especially for dual citizens with a valid foreign passport.  Unfortunately my Portuguese and my knowledge of Brazilian online legal resources are both insufficient for me to investigate this myself.

Comment: According to the [Brazilian government site](https://www.gov.br/pf/pt-br/assuntos/passaporte/ajuda/duvidas/inicio/inicio-brasileiro-com-dupla-nacionalidade-pode), if you show your other nationality passport and not your Brazilian ID ("RG"), you will be treated as a foreigner. This applies to both when entering or leaving Brazil.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you'll be OK to travel to Brazil.  From [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=BR&NV=Brazil&AC=US&AV=United+States&DC=BR&DV=Brazil&TC=PA&TV=Panama&h=81cf3bd1d7bd36a710c56e7a11fb12999674f24) (italics mine):

> ### Destination - Brazil (BR)
>
> **Passport**
>
> Passport required.
>
> **Passport Exemptions:**
>
> Nationals of Brazil with a national ID card .
> Nationals of Brazil with an emergency passport.
>
> **Document Validity:**
>
> *Nationals of Brazil are allowed to enter with an expired passport.*
>
> When nationals of Brazil travel with an emergency passport, a Laissez-Passer issued by Brazil or a national ID card, it must be valid on arrival.
>
> ...
>
> ### Transit - Panama (PA)
>
> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
> *Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours.* They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

You'll need to carry both of your passports to prove to the airlines' satisfaction that you'll be admitted to Brazil upon your arrival.

**Edit:**  The return trip is dicier.  If you can get to the departure gate, the airline will probably let you board, as a US passport is sufficient to travel to the US via Panama.

However, as pointed out by [Doc's answer,](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/117189/31165) Brazilian law requires Brazilian citizens to enter and exit the country using a Brazilian passport.  If you attempt to conceal your Brazilian citizenship from the Brazilian exit officers, your US passport will not have a valid visa or entry stamp from your visit, which will raise questions. (One way to get around this would be to renew your passport while you're there, which would obviate the whole problem.)

<strike>Upon your return, you should be OK traveling on your US passport alone.   However, if there are exit controls upon leaving Brazil, you may need to show them your expired Brazilian passport to prove that you entered the country legally.</strike>

Comment: But will Brazil let the traveler leave with an expired Brazilian passport?

Comment: @phoog: why does it matter? The OP can leave Brazil (and enter the US) using his valid US passport.

Comment: @David Brazil could have a law requiring Brazilian citizens to have a valid passport in order to leave the country.  The US passport will not have a Brazilian visa or entry stamp, so it will be necessary to claim Brazilian citizenship on exit.

Comment: Brazilian citizens must enter and exit the country using a Brazilian passport.

Comment: @Doc but the question is whether they can use an *expired* passport to leave the country (they can apparently use one to enter), and what would happen if they tried to?

Comment: @phoog Can you name a country on the planet where you can use an expired passport to depart?

Comment: @Doc not with any degree of certainty, but that doesn't mean that such a country doesn't exist.  For a dual citizen, the prospect of using an expired passport to prove a legal right to be in the country in connection with a valid foreign passport is not so bizarre.  For example, I am a dual citizen of an EU country and a non-EU country.  I suspect that it would be possible to pass Schengen exit controls with a valid non-EU passport, using an expired EU passport to explain the lack of entry and exit stamps in the non-EU passport.

Comment: @Doc on the other hand, the US has a law requiring its citizens to "bear a valid United States passport" when leaving the country, so the reverse whould not be lawful, although in practice it is possible because the US does not do much to enforce that law.